# How do I force Apache's CloseableHttpClient to use TLSv1.2?

Tags: java, apache, ssl, tls1.2

In Java, I need to get the Apache CloseableHttpClient to use TLSv1.2. Currently it looks like it uses HTTP/1.1. How can I specify the protocol version in the code below?

```
 public static void main(String [] args){
                                try {
                      SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
                                  @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
                                  CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
                                    .setSSLSocketFactory(new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext.getDefault(), new String[] { "TLSv1.2" }, null, SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getDefaultHostnameVerifier()))
                                    .build();
                      HttpHost target = new HttpHost("https://www.sometest.com", 443, "https");
                      String call = "/vivisimo/cgi-bin/velocity";
                      HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(call);
                      System.out.println("Protocol Version:" + getRequest.getProtocolVersion());
                     } catch (Exception e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                                  }
}
```

Comment: Do you understand the difference between TLS and HTTP?

Comment: @JoshuaHedges please check the running code added to the answer that demonstrates how to force a specific TLS version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While creating SSLContext specify that it has to use TLS instead of getting the default one:

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContextBuilder.create().build();
```

Or:

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(....);
```

Or simply use:

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom().build()
```

Based on your code here is the running example (it makes the connection to `google.com`). I have enabled the debug log. Look for `negotiated protocol: TLSv1.2` in the log. Now, change the `TLS` version to `1.1` while creating the http client(`new String[] { "TLSv1.1" }`), run the program and observe that string 'negotiated protocol..' changed to `TLSv1.1`.
What you earlier printed that is HTTP protocol version.

```
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContextBuilder;
import org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.StringWriter;

public class ForceTLS12 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.Log", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog");
            System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.showdatetime","true");
            System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.http","DEBUG");
            System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.http.wire","DEBUG");
            //SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
            CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
                    .setSSLSocketFactory(new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(SSLContexts.custom().build(), new String[] { "TLSv1.2" }, null, SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getDefaultHostnameVerifier()))
                    .build();
            HttpHost target = new HttpHost("www.google.com", 443, "https");
            //String call = "/vivisimo/cgi-bin/velocity";
            HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(target.toURI());
            CloseableHttpResponse resposne = httpclient.execute(getRequest);

            System.out.println(resposne.getEntity().getContentType());
            System.out.println("Protocol Version:" + getRequest.getProtocolVersion());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This executable code sample is available at [github](https://github.com/fiveobjects/reference/blob/master/java/misc/src/main/java/org/openapex/samples/misc/http/ForceTLS12Stack57260060.java) as well.

Comment: I added SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS"); to the start of this code, moved the commented code out and replaced the first line above. I also referenced the sslContext variable in that line instead of SSLContext. It still isn't working for some reason.

Comment: Na, it's still saying HTTP 1.1

Comment: Can you edit the question to reflect your current code and make it runnable code.

Comment: I updated it so it doesn't make the call but it should print out the protocol. I'm assuming the getRequest.getProtocolVersion() will print out TLS.

Comment: I have added the full running code with debug log enabled. Check this out and let me know whether your problem is solved.

Comment: @JoshuaHedges please update whether this answer helped you to get the clarifications and resolve your problem. If yes, please accept the answer :)